# How can I add tags to a pdf document using PHP?

Tags: php, function, pdf, tags, document

I wonder how I can add tags to a PDF document using PHP. The idea is that I can search for a document using the tag that I assigned it previously.

Comment: Do you mean assigning tags to specific parts of the document, or to the entire document?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I meant to the entire document, for example, assigning a tag to a .pdf file, .doc file, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your hint is [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/PDF.html) to manipulate PDF tags. There is a [PHP wrapper/driver](https://github.com/romainneutron/PHPExiftool) for it. BIG NOTE that it is not recommended for production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install pdf to image converter on your server, here is the settings:
Please update the server with this package, so the conversion functionality works.

you can found the files i used on local server from
i used on windows using follwing instructions

1. Install gs909w32.exe (http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/gs909w32.exe )
2. Install ImageMagick-6.8.9-4-Q16-x64-dll.exe ([Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) )
3. paste  "php_imagick.dll"  file in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\
4. include extensions= php_imagick.dll in php.ini file

It will convert your .pdf document to images (1 image/1 page), then you can tag....